# assigning 0x00 to an array in C?

Tags: c, hex, character-arrays

I was reading over an slide where they had this:

```
int current = 0;
buffer[current]=0x00;
```

where buffer is just a character array `char buffer[300];`

if `0x00` is a representation of null and we replace it with NULL `buffer[current]=NULL` gives the following error when compiling:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

can someone please explain what does the `buffer[current]=0x00;` means? does this check for end of the array list?

Comment: It sets the first element of the array to a "hex" 0 ?

Comment: That would be my guess.

Comment: Don't confuse the `NULL` pointer with the NUL byte.  They sound similar but are different.

Comment: @Rizier123 why use hex when you can just assign the 0 ?

Comment: The real question here is whether buffer is being used to hold a string, or just an array of small integers. You haven't given enough context to answer that question. However, using `0x00` to terminate a string would be unusual. Typically, one uses the character constant `'\0'` to terminate a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is a macro which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant.

Both these two definitions are valid for NULL:

```
#define NULL  0
```

or

```
#define NULL  ((void *) 0))
```

if the latter is used in your compiler:

```
char buffer[300];
buffer[current]=NULL;
```

You have an invalid program as you cannot assign a pointer value to integer object.

`((void *) 0)` is a value of a pointer type. Use `0` or the equivalent hexadecimal value `0x00` to assign `0` to an integer object.

Comment: so the `0x00` set the buffer to null?

Comment: It set it to `0`. Note that `0` is also the value of the ASCII null character, sometimes called NUL (and not null or NULL).

Comment: And it does not set the buffer to `0` but one element only. `buffer[current] = 0;` set the `buffer` element  at position `current` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` is a compiler warning in GCC and `NULL` almost is define for 0x0 :

```
#define NULL 0
```

or

```
#define NULL (void *)0
```

so in later case if you assign NULL into integer instead of pointer you get compiler warning in GCC.